# C++ Operator>> Overloading with Mutator?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, pointer-to-member, mutators

I am trying to figure out a way (if possible) to overload the >> operator to function correctly with a mutator. For example, I want to write:

```
myClass obj;
cin >> obj.setValue;
```

and have it correctly set the obj's private value using the available mutator in a single line. I know I can use a temporary variable to store the cin and set the obj value with that, but I'm wondering if there is a more concise method such as this. I'm a novice programmer so this is my futile attempt within myClass:

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, void (myClass::*pt)(double newValue)) {
    double temp;
    in >> temp;
    pt(temp);
    return in;
}
```

I know I can simply overload the myClass as a whole to accept:

```
cin >> myClass;
```

but this would prevent me from setting different individual values within myClass at different times.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `cin >> obj.setValue;` can't be made to work - it's simply not a valid C++ syntax (assuming `setValue` is a member function of `myClass`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> obj.setValue` or `cin >> &obj.setValue` are examples of **invalid** C++. There's no way of getting a reference/pointer to a *member function* of a particular instance of a `class`.

What you could do is instead package the `this` pointer and a *pointer to member function* in a small `struct`, and overload `operator>>` on that instead:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg>
struct setter_t
{
    T* _this;
    void (T::*_ptr)(Arg);
};

template <typename T, typename Arg>
auto setter(T& x, void (T::*ptr)(Arg))
{
    return setter_t<T, Arg>{&x, ptr};
}

template <typename T, typename Arg>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, setter_t<T, Arg> s) 
{
    Arg temp;
    in >> temp;
    (s._this->*s._ptr)(temp);
    return in;
}
```

Usage:

```
myClass obj;
std::cin >> setter(obj, &myClass::setValue);
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FHPrGlOndCukIqY9)

---

Here's a C++17 solution that doesn't unnecessarily store `_ptr` inside `setter_t`. Usage:

```
std::cin >> setter<&myClass::setValue>(obj);
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bjn4WdoJHS0gp6Hq)

Answer (score 0):

You could make .setValue() return a non const reference to a Functor (a class that overrides the operator() ), then make that Functor override the

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, MySetterFunctor &x){
    double temp;
    is >> temp;
    x(temp);
    return is;
}
```

The functor would be initialized by obj, receive a pointer to obj and use the actual obj's setter method in its 
    void operator()(double v){ obj->set_value(v);}

For that extra bit of hackery, you could make setValue a non-const public member so that you can just call it like std::cin >> obj.setValue and also normally do x.setValue(someDouble). You may make obj.set_value a protected member function and make MySetterFunctor a friend class of obj.

```
class Obj{
    public:
        friend class MySetterFunctor;
        MySetterFunctor setValue;
    ...
}
```

Big disclaimer: This is all theoretical talk, I am not sure one would want to do this but I believe it would let you do what you want.